# What is a networking monitoring tool/plugin that can provide detailed information on requests in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http

I use a tool called tamperdata in Firefox that provides a decent listing  of the request information.   I think it does a better job filtering out the content and also provides a way to tamper the request.  For example, tamperdata lists the cookies and posts per request.  The other tools in firefox and chrome don't do that.  Is there a chrome tool like tamperdata that does a good job at detailing request information?  I am mainly looking for a tool in chrome that does this?

Answer (score 1):

If you activate the Google Developer Tools from Extra->Developer Tools (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) there is a 'Network' tab. This tab if you click on a resource on the page, it will give you the request and response HTTP headers:

[image]

Comment: Yea, that is the tool I was avoiding.  It prints the headers but they are formatted in a way that I can easily access them like with tamper data.  for example, if I have 20 cookies, they are all printed on one line it the google tool.  Also, I think some of the requests are lost in the tool.  E.g. if there is a redirect, the request list starts all over.  Tamperdata does a good job of queueing all REQUESTS.